# Distance between the noise and the corrupted signal

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, signal-processing, law-of-large-numbers

How can one formalize the fact that the law of $X+Z$ where $X \in \mathbb{R}^d$ is any vector-valued random variable and $Z\sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2 \mathbf{I}_d)$ closely resembles the law of $Z$ if $\sigma^2$ is sufficiently large ? $X$ and $Z$ are supposed independent. Ideally, I would like to prove that some distance/divergence between the law of $X+Z$ and $Z$ approaches zero as $\sigma^2\to \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

If  were Gaussian, for example, with a non-zero mean, $_{+}=_+_≠_.$

$\displaystyle \lim_{\sigma\rightarrow \infty} (\mu_{X+Z} - \mu_{Z})=\mu_X \ne 0.$

So the difference between the law of $X+Z$ and the law of $Z$ does not approach zero.

Comment: This was meant as a comment ...  Not an "answer" for now, but let's see how the discussion goes.  Thanks.

Comment: $X$ is any *fixed* vector-valued random variable, i.e. the law of $X$ cannot change or depend on the law of $Z$.

Comment: $X$ is constant?  or a random variable?

Comment: Okay, $X\sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma_0^2 \mathbf{I}_d)$, for example.  A fixed distribution, whereas you want to show what happens as the distribution of $Z$ spreads out, yes?

Comment: Well, if $X$ were Gaussian with a non-zero mean, $\mu_{X+Z} = \mu_X + \mu_Z \ne \mu_Z$.